# Avd shuts down by itself after opening google play

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play, android-virtual-device

Avd turns itself off after opening google play.
There is no option to do without google play.
I am creating a pixel 2 device, with android 10 q. I didn't change anything in the settings. I tried to change the graphics (automatic), but the graphics settings are locked

**Logs**

2022-02-21 14:51:11,099 [1485213]   INFO - b.PhysicalDeviceChangeListener - emulator-5558 state changed to OFFLINE
2022-02-21 14:51:11,099 [1485213]   INFO - mpl.AdbDeviceFileSystemService - Device changed: emulator-5558
2022-02-21 14:51:11,100 [1485214]   WARN -            #com.android.ddmlib - Failed to start monitoring emulator-5558
2022-02-21 14:51:11,102 [1485216]   WARN - ea.emulator.EmulatorController - android.emulation.control.EmulatorController/streamScreenshot call failed - UNAVAILABLE: Network closed for unknown reason
2022-02-21 14:51:11,103 [1485217]   INFO - ea.emulator.EmulatorController - Disconnected from Pixel 2 API 29 (5558)
2022-02-21 14:51:11,103 [1485217]   WARN - ea.emulator.EmulatorController - android.emulation.control.EmulatorController/streamNotification call failed - UNAVAILABLE: Network closed for unknown reason
2022-02-21 14:51:11,103 [1485217]   WARN - ea.emulator.EmulatorController - android.emulation.control.EmulatorController/streamClipboard call failed - UNAVAILABLE: Network closed for unknown reason
2022-02-21 14:51:11,175 [1485289]   INFO - manager.EmulatorProcessHandler - Emulator: Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)
2022-02-21 14:51:11,175 [1485289]   WARN - manager.EmulatorProcessHandler - Emulator terminated with exit code 139
2022-02-21 14:51:11,349 [1485463]   INFO - b.PhysicalDeviceChangeListener - emulator-5558 disconnected
2022-02-21 14:51:11,349 [1485463]   INFO - mpl.AdbDeviceFileSystemService - Device disconnected: emulator-5558
2022-02-21 14:51:31,081 [1505195]   INFO - manager.EmulatorProcessHandler - Emulator: glTexImage2D: got err pre :( 0x505 internal 0x1907 format 0x1907 type 0x1401
2022-02-21 14:51:48,167 [1522281]   WARN - ea.emulator.EmulatorController - android.emulation.control.EmulatorController/getVmState call failed - UNAVAILABLE: io exception
2022-02-21 14:52:32,526 [1566640]   INFO - penapi.wm.impl.GlobalMenuLinux - frame peer is null, wait for connection
2022-02-21 14:52:32,526 [1566640]   WARN - penapi.wm.impl.GlobalMenuLinux - can't obtain XID of window: com.intellij.openapi.ui.FrameWrapper$MyJFrame[frame9,72,27,1208x693,invalid,hidden,layout=java.awt.BorderLayout,title=Android Emulator - My Application,resizable,maximized,defaultCloseOperation=DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE,rootPane=,rootPaneCheckingEnabled=true], skip global menu unbinding

Comment: Can you share the logs ?

Comment: i added logs to the question

Comment: can you try cold boot or wipe data before boot?

Comment: This logs includes warnings not any error.